# Update multiple values in a row based on the foreign key name

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to fix it for 2 hours and I can't find solution

```sql
Table product
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned| NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| product_name   | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| product_cat_id | int             | NO   | FK  | NULL    |                |  
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

table Product Category
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10)         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| category_name  | varchar(255)    | NO   | FK  | NULL    |                | 
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have 500 products and I have to set product_cat_id to all rows based on the product category name (keyboard)

How can I achieve this in MySQL?

this one works  as expected however 'set.a.profile_category_id = 10' can not be hard coded. It should be SET a.product_category_id = b.id where b.name='Keyboard' but it doesn't work as expected

````
UPDATE product a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_categories b
    ON a.product_category_id = b.id  
    SET a.product_category_id = 10
    ```
````

Comment: update your question add also a proper data sample and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

If name columns from product and productcategory represents same information the you can use

```
UPDATE product
INNER JOIN productcategory  ON productcategory.name = product.name
SET product.product _cat_id=  productcategory.id;
```